# Is a mutex required when accessing references for elements in a list of vectors captured in a lambda for a worker thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>

...

{
    using namespace std;

    unsigned cpus = 8; // number of threads
    vector<vector<uint64_t>> aprimes(cpus);
    vector<thread> workers;
    for(int cpu: boost::irange(cpus)){
        vector<uint64_t>& tprimes = aprimes[cpu];
        workers.push_back(thread([=, &tprimes](){
            // top work on tprimes
            tprimes.push_back(5);
        }));
    }
    for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(), [](thread &t)
    {
        t.join();
    });
    for(auto vec: aprimes){
        for(int val: vec){
            cout << val << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I am capturing a reference to each vector (tprimes) in my list of vectors aprimes for the lambdas used in each thread.  Is this capture safe?  Should I be using a mutex or other access method here?  The code does work, but I am unsure if this will fail later.

Comment: Why this convoluted for loop on `irange`? Just to complicate it?

Comment: @Slava because I like it more and I can do fun things like this: for(const unsigned cpu: boost::irange(cpus))  to further show intent of how that value should be used.  I really should have used that for my code in this post to say to other develppers "hey, don't mess with this index, mmm kay?".  Also, because I like it more.  I like it a lot.  Besides ++i is soooo 1990s... ;-)

Comment: I did not mean using old good loop. My point is you overcomplicated simple thing. First 2 line of the loop can be replaced with: `for( vector<uint64_t>& tprimes : aprimes ) ...` or even `for ( auto &tprimes : aprimes ) ...`

Comment: @Slava I pulled this code out of working code to ask a specific question about how I was referencing the vectors in aprimes list.  I actually use the cpu variable inside the lambda.  This is not shown because it was not relevant to the question.  Yes, looping over the aprimes vector would have been a nice solution as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is safe.  When we talk about data races and undefined behavior we are talking about multiple threads modifying the same shared object.  In your case you do not have this.  Each element of `aprimes` is it's own distinct object so each worker thread is working on an object only it is accessing.  Even though they all happen to be inside `aprimes` doesn't change this as long as you do not modify `aprimes`.  In that case it is just like having a bunch of vector declared one after another.

The only caveat with this is your main thread is not allowed to modify `aprimes` and it is not allowed to modify any of the elements in `aprimes`.  If you do, then you will have multiple thread writing to a shared object without synchronization which is a data race and undefined behavior.

---

Do note that one thing that can happen when you do this is [false sharing](https://web.archive.org/web/20200302130554/https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads).  If you had a `vector<int>` with 4 elements and each thread gets one of the ints then what will happen is even though no thread is sharing the object, they are sharing the cache line the object lives in.  This causes the CPU to constantly have to synchronize the CPU caches when one of the ints is updated because it only can work on a cache line level.  This effectively will make the program run like it had no threads since all 4 threads can't modify the cache line concurrently.  In this case since we are dealing with vectors it should not be a problem, but it is something to be mindful of.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the *aprimes* vector doesn't change (add stuff), it won't re-allocate.

As long as it doesn't reallocate, the various *tprimes* vector won't move around. Each *tprimes* have their own location in memory. Each thread will be reading and writing from/to a different vector.

As such, it is safe.